# Is there a way to add a function (references another column for calculation)to a column in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to add a column to an existing table with a max() function to populate the column in postgresql. Example:

```
Alter table stable
Add column max_veggie INTEGER;

--populate the column max_veggie---
        Insert into stable (max_veggie)
        Values(Max(veggie_id));
        FROM stable;

--the code for the table would be max(veggie_id)
```

the error:

> cannot be referenced from this part of the query.column

also I tried:

```
update stable
set max_veggie = MAX(veggie_id);
```

error at M on max()......

I expected to populate a column with a maximum from another column.

Comment: Why? 1) That value is going to change with additions to the table. 2) Why have the same value in all rows?

Comment: If table `stable` has a `created_at` column or similar then you do not need to add a new column but create a view with column `max(veggie_id) over (order by created_at) as max_veggie` that would hold the max of `veggie_id` at the time the record was created.